# Ignoring int? property when the value is 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an issue with my Web API code: I have an entity called `player` which is an int thus it will always default to 0. I am using ASP.NET Core 5 Web API with EF Core 5.

The API data is being consumed in a Xamarin forms app.

My `Player` entity and yes this is my view model before you ask I want the Team Id to be their when a player is being added to a team but not when their not.

```
public class Player
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + Surname; }
    }

    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }     
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see from above I tried using `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault` but when I inspect the json which is down below you will see TeamId=0 is still their. Its for crud operations so am using 0 to say when to add or update.

Json being sent to server is

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "CoachId": null,
    "TeamId": 0,
    "Year": 2019,
    "FirstName": "Test FirstName",
    "Surname": "Test LastName",
    "FullName": "Test FirstName Test LastName",
    "DOB": null,
    "Weight": 118.9,
    "Height": null,
    "Gender": 0,
    "Photo": null,
    "Age": 2019,
    "EmailAddress": "test@test.com",
    "TB": 0.0, "OP": 0.0, "PU": 0.0, "PB": 0.0,
    "BP": null,
    "Status": 0,
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "LastModifiedBy": null,
    "LastUpdatedDate": null,
    "CreatedDate": "2021-11-12T02:55:14.022918+00:00"
}
```

It's the `TeamId` I wish to remove from the above json which I'm serialising below

JsonConvert.SerializeObject

```
 public async Task<HttpStatusCode> AddToPlayer(Player Player)
 {
        Player.CreatedBy = db.GetActiveUser();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Player);
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();
        var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        AddAuthenicationHeader();
        // Do the actual request and await the response
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(Constants.BaseUrl + Constants.ApiSegmant + Constants.AddPlayer, httpContent);
        return httpResponse.StatusCode;
 }
```

Comment: 0 *is not* default value for `int?` - can you please clarify what you want to achieve (and ideally edit code to show [MCVE] without bunch of unrelated code).

Comment: Whats your expectations? Its not clear yet.

Comment: I dont want TeamId to be in the jason when its value of zero

Comment: Your issue seems to be shared with others: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/779#issuecomment-650614383

Comment: They appear to be wanting zero in the json i dont want the whole teamid attriubute in the file at all when value is zero

Comment: Its an “int?” - the default is null. Test the value of Player.TeamId just before doing SerializeObject. I bet it has “0” instead if null. If so, then find out why. Or if you want to turn zero into null, then do if (player.teamid == 0) player.teamid = null.

Comment: I had to do the check both ends first in the payload am sending and also in the web api side but its fixed now. @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: Glad that worked. Go ahead and add "Your Answer" below, showing your code with the suggested fix added. Then anyone else who encounters this situation will know exactly what to do!